# New Rapoo E2800P keyboard not working when plugged in

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I just bought this keyboard http://www.amazon.de/Rapoo-Wireless-deutsches-Tastaturl... for my laptop and connected it via the USB loading cable to my laptop. I bought it to replace an old keyboard from the same brand that broke after I spilled water on it.

Now, the new keyboard doesn't work when I plug it in. The battery indicator on the keyboard says the battery is loading, but pressing keys does nothing. I also don't see any new devices in the device manager.

Why won't my keyboard work?

Answer (score 1):

I assume by now you found out yourself...but the E2800P is a wireless keyboard. The USB cable is only used for charging the built-in battery, not to connect it to your computer. It should have come with a small USB dongle/plug to be plugged into your computer.